# Probability: A and B play a game with two six-sided dice. Each die has some red faces and some blue faces. The two dice are thrown simultaneously.

Tags: probability

A and B play a game with two six-sided dice. Each die has some red faces and some blue faces. The two dice are thrown simultaneously. If the top face of each die is the same color, A wins, and if they are different colors, B wins. One die has ﬁve red faces and one blue face. How many red faces does the other die have if both players have the same chance of winning?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 2):

If there are $r$ red and $b$ blue faces on the second die, then A will win with probability
$$\frac56\cdot\frac r6+\frac 16\cdot\frac b6. $$
This is supposed to be $\frac12$, and of course $r+b=6$. Solve these equations.

---

Once you solved the problem that way, perform an excessive (contactless) facepalm and contemplate why you didn't see the solution right away without computation.